# Sonicwall NSA with ping/Internet to wake

Tags: hyper-v, sonicwall

We have an Sonicwall NSA with some VMs running on Hyper-V in 2 x LANs connected to it.

The VMs in the 1st LAN are fine however the VMs in the second LAN keep losing their WAN connection and therefore we cannot access them remotely (we can access them from the LAN).

To fix the issue we just log into the console of the VM and ping the gateway or open IE and browse a website.

This then fixes the issue but only for a few hours until it happens again.

Any ideas? (nothing else is using the same IPs)

Comment: ALso when the issue happens not all of the VMs are effected on the 2nd LAN - just 1 of them and always a different one.

Comment: At first glance, this sounds like a dynamic routing issue. The command `Route Print` at the command prompt will show the current dynamic routes. I'd run this command when it breaks and then again immediately after 'fixing' it by pinging. The solution will probably be a configuration issue on the Sonicwall or adding a static route to the VM's.

Comment: Thats what we thought as well however the routing table does not change before or after fixing the issue.

Comment: What about `tracert` - how does that compare before and after?

Comment: A tracert with the issue just times out and when the issue is fixed works fine without any timing out

Comment: I'm going to have to conclude that it's a routing issue on the Sonicwall or another routing device.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7505/discussion-between-adam-and-dan)